# How to run chrome webdriver hidden (not headless) and be able to attach and detach to it

Tags: python, c#, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to create a program where I need the chrome driver to do its work in the background until I click a certain button, which should pop up the chrome window so I can see what its doing at the point of time. But If I close that window, it should not stop the process instead just detach it and the browser becomes invisible again until I again press that certain button which I will program it for.
I am not talking about using in headless mode here.

Does any one have any idea? I am using some similar programs which are doing same exact thing but I cannot understand how they are doing it.

When I close the browser window, the window disappears from the screen and the taskbar, but it is still present in task manager until the process action is not completed. Then only it exits.

So Basically, however many times i click browse window and close that window, it doesnt break the process.

Can someone explain how to achieve such function in C# or python. Again I am not taking about headless or moving the window to some random far location. When its running in background, its only in task manager and not in taskbar.

I have tried detach, but then I cannot attach back to it.I have tried headless, then I cannot attach back to it. I have tried using remote debugger port but I still cannot attach back to the window. And whenever I close the browser window, it stops the action altogether.

Comment: Why not minimize the window? You can start the browser and then minimize it.

Comment: That is not the solution I need. Handling a large number of windows would be troublesome and miss clicks / human error can cause errors and failures if the minimized window is handled incorrectly.

Comment: I recommend trying playwright. Selenium doesn't have this kind of capability